# Git remote branch workflow

Tags: git, github

We're using GitHub here.  I have a friend who branched our master branch, and I want to checkout his branch, make a few mods, then put them into his branch.

My thought is to grab his branch using `git checkout --track -b origin/my_friends_branch` then making my mods and committing, and then....not really sure.  I'd like to send him a pull request but am not sure how to do that on a remote branch?

Also not sure if I should take the opportunity to dip my toes in the `rebase` waters, which I've been slow to try, simply out of ignorance, and whether when working on a remote branch it makes special sense to do so.

Comment: Is his branch in your repository, or did he fork the repository and the branch lives in the fork?  FWIW, there's no need to rebase in this scenario.  I'd avoid it until you get a good grasp on Git and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git pull --all
git checkout my_friends_branch
git push origin my_friends_branch
```